# Luxon.js ISO 8601 parsing

Tags: javascript, date, iso8601, luxon

I'm using Luxon.js to handle Date and I'm trying to parse some ISO string which comes from the server. It has this format

```
2019-04-04T12:12:07+03:00
```

and I'm using Luxon's method - fromISO which should parse this str

```
DateTime.fromISO("2019-04-04T12:12:07+03:00", "dd LLLL yyyy")
```

I'm expect to see ***04 April 2019 - 15:12*** in output but it returns ***04 April 2019 - 12:12*** somehow and I can't understand why it happens?

Am I doing something wrong? 
because when I'm trying to use this ISO string **2019-04-04T12:12:07.756Z**
it works like a charm. But I don't understand why the previous one isn't working and what should I do to make it working?

I'll appreciate any help!

P.S. to be honest, I have some gaps of my knowledge about ISO time so sorry if the question is stupid.

Comment: Your starting timestamp is in the "+3:00" time zone, three hours ahead of UTC. 12:12:07 in that timezone is 09:12:07 UTC.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Pointy. Let's clarify it a bit. Let's imagine that my timezone is UTC+3. so is this string **2019-04-04T12:12:07+03:00** means that this record was done in 12.12   and I should add 3 hours (and it will be 15.12)  or it means that it was created in 15.12 my time and the ISO just substract this 3 hours?   and why this string **2019-04-04T12:12:07.756Z** has been parsed correctly?

Comment: Right, if you are in the +3:00 timezone, then *creating* the date gives you a UTC date 3 hours *earlier*. Converting that back to string form (apparently) uses the local time zone, so that adds the 3 hours back.  (I agree that thinking about time zones is really confusing!)

Comment: yeah, you are right. It's a bit annoying. Thank you Pointy for your well detailed explanation. 
I still have question about Luxon parsing and why it works in one case but isn't work in different case but at least now I have clear vision how it can be parsed. Thanks you a lot.

Comment: @Velidan—your problem isn't the parsing, it's the formatting. As Pointy said, the time component of the timestamp is "12:12:07+03:00", that is, 12:12:07 in timezone +3. If you are in timezone +3, then the time will be "12:12:07", which is what you are getting. To get 15:12 you'd need to be in timezone +6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`2019-04-04T12:12:07+03:00` says "in a zone with an offset of +3, it is 12:12". It isn't telling Luxon to add 3 hours; it's providing the context in which the time was expressed. For example, because zones whose offset is +3 have local times 3 hours ahead of UTC (that's what it means), then in England it's 9:12. The point is that it's a specific time on the planet, and the +3 is just telling you what rule was used in turning that time into a string.

Luxon takes in all that information and figures out what time it really is, which in its conception of time is the number of milliseconds that have transpired since the beginning of 1970 in UTC. It can then translate that into any zone's local time. Of course, if your computer is in a zone whose offset is +3, then that local time is 12:12:

```js
-> TZ=Europe/Moscow node
> DateTime = require("luxon").DateTime
[Function: DateTime]
> var dt = DateTime.fromISO("2019-04-04T12:12:07+03:00")
undefined
> dt.toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_24_SIMPLE)
'12:12'
```

My computer is actually on the US east coast, so I see a very different local time:

```js
-> node
> DateTime = require("luxon").DateTime
[Function: DateTime]
> var dt = DateTime.fromISO("2019-04-04T12:12:07+03:00")
undefined
> dt.toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_24_SIMPLE)
'05:12'
```

That's because my offset is -4, which means the local time here is 7 hours earlier than the +3 in the original string.

With my computer in any zone, I could of course tell Luxon to express the date in any other zone:

```js
> dt.toUTC().toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_24_SIMPLE)
'09:12'
> dt.setZone("Europe/Moscow").toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_24_SIMPLE)
'12:12'
> dt.setZone("Asia/Tokyo").toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_24_SIMPLE)
'18:12'
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Now it's clear for me